# test express API requires local server

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js, supertest, should.js

I've read i can run mocha test in an Express application (nodeJS) with super test and therefore it is not required to run the app in a different terminal session.
Whatever i try it always ends with a connection error.

To configure our continuous integration it is evident the integration and unit test (mocha, supertest, should) should be able to run without the node server is also running

The written tests are to validate our app's internal api end points
Who can explain how to run the tests without running the express server of the app so they can be integrated with for example strider

Answer (score 7):

You need to split out your production code that calls `app.listen` and make sure that does not get executed during a mocha test run. I put all of my routes and settings code in `app/index.js` and then have a separate file `app/server.js` that has just a tiny bit of code to start listening, connect to the database, etc. But most of my application details are configured in `app/index.js` so I can test them with supertest.

```
//index.js
var app = require("express")();

app.get("/", function (req, res) {
  res.type("text");
  res.send("Welcome home");
});

module.exports = app;
```

---

```
//server.js
#!/usr/bin/env node
var app = require("./index");
app.listen(3000);
```

---

```
//index.mocha.js
var app = require("./index");
var request = require("supertest")(app);
var expect = require("expectacle");

describe("the home page", function () {
  it("should welome me in plain text", function(done) {
    request.get("/")
      .expect(200)
      .expect("Content-Type", "text/plain; charset=utf-8")
      .end(function (error, result) {
        expect(error).toBeFalsy();
        expect(result.text).toBe("Welcome home");
        done();
      });
  });
});
```

Comment: thanks for the feedback. can you share a same app/server.js file and app/index.js as you are using?

Comment: Does this still run an Express process listening on some supertest-specified port, or does everything run in one process? (i.e., if I run a debugger on index.mocha.js, can I step into my Express app code?)

Comment: Yes, the server listens on an ephemeral port (OS selects an available high port). It's all one node process (both the supertest client and the express server run in the same process). Yes, you can debug it and step through the code.